# SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress is being deprecated

Tags: swift, reachability, system-configuration

Apple has deprecated `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress` and while the documentation does not state that `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` is also deprecated it looks like both are on the way out.  Apple does not suggest a successor so my question is what would be a good way to achieve a similar result to test reachability?  Here is the code I was using:

```swift
var currentReachabilityStatus: ReachabilityStatus {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    
    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return .notReachable
    }
    
    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return .notReachable
    }
...
```

My current code works but the feature is being retired.

Comment: I use `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress` but don't see a deprecation warning symbol for it, not even after I change the deployment target to iOS 17.0.

Comment: @ElTomato it will be marked deprecated from iOS 17.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use Network's NWPathMonitor
[Method explanation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-nwpathmonitor)

Example:

```
import Network

class Reachability {
  let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
  let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
  
  init() {
    monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
      if path.status == .satisfied {
        // network reachable
      } else {
        // network not reachable
      }
    }
    
    monitor.start(queue: queue)
  }
}
```